# Fastlane frameit unsupported screen size when deliver to App store

Tags: screenshot, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot, fastlane-deliver, frameit

Using Swift5, iOS-12.2, Xcode-10.2(10E125) and running everything with a GitLab CI,

There seem to be an issue with screenshot **screen sizes** during App release step (using Fastlane's `deliver`). The screenshots are created nicely (with Fastlane's `snapshot` and `frameit` tools).

But having updated to newest iOS-, Swift- and Xcode-versions now suddenly breaks my working example of Fastlane. I now get the following error:

`Unsupported screen size [1446, 2948] for path '/Users/user/Documents/Programieren/iPhone_applications/Learning/Watch/MyApp/builds/aMDc3etB/0/myusername/MyAppName/fastlane/screenshots/de-DE/iPhone 8 Plus-01Screenshot_de_framed.png'`

Could there be something wrong with Fastlane:

- either at the `frameit` step (since framed images are bigger in size than what `snapshot` created)
- or at the App release step (since maybe Apple changed something with the screen sizes accepted).

I am wondering if the fact that I run everything with GitLab CI has an influence (but it should't). What could be the cause of the Fastlane failure concerning screen sizes of screenshots at the `deliver` step ?

For an iPhone8-Plus example - what I realised:

--> screenshots after Fastlane `snapshot` step are [1242 × 2208] pixels in size

--> framed-screenshots after the Fastlane `frameit` step are [1446 × 2948] pixels in size

The Apple app store asks for [1242 × 2208] pixel sized images - therefore "framed" ones will never be accepted !!

Could there be something wrong with `frameit` ???

Should I choose different iOS devices in my Snapfile (see below) ? And if yes, which ones ??? (i.e. it used to be the case that the App store needed an iPhone8 Plus sized screenshot [5.5"]. Did that change maybe ??)

Here is my Fastfile:

```rb
lane :screenshots do
    snapshot
    frameit(silver: true, path: './fastlane/screenshots')
end
```

Here is my Snapfile:

```rb
workspace "MyApp.xcworkspace"
scheme "MyAppUITests"
devices([
    "iPhone 8 Plus",
    "iPhone SE"
])
languages([
    "en-US",
    "de-DE"
])
localize_simulator true
clear_previous_screenshots true
erase_simulator true
reinstall_app true
```

Here is my Framefile.json file:

```rb
{
    "device_frame_version": "latest",
    "default": {
        "keyword": {
            "fonts": [
                {
                    "font": "./fonts/SF-UI-Display-Semibold.otf",
                    "supported": ["de-DE", "en-US"]
                },
                {
                    "font": "./fonts/Chinese.ttf",
                    "supported": ["zcmn-Hans"]
                }
            ]
        },
        "title": {
            "fonts": [
                {
                    "font": "./fonts/SF-UI-Display-Regular.otf",
                    "supported": ["de-DE", "en-US"]
                },
                {
                    "font": "./fonts/Chinese.ttf",
                    "supported": ["zcmn-Hans"]
                }
            ],
            "color": "#203943"
        },
        "background": "./background.jpg",
        "padding": 50,
        "stack_title" : false,
        "title_below_image": false,
        "show_complete_frame": false,
    },


    "data": [
        {
            "filter": "01",
            "keyword": {
                "color": "#4B849B"
            }
        },
        {
            "filter": "02",
            "keyword": {
                "color": "#4B849B"
            }
        },
        {
            "filter": "03",
            "keyword": {
                "color": "#4B849B"
            }
        },
        {
            "filter": "04",
            "keyword": {
                "color": "#4B849B"
            }
        },
        {
            "filter": "05",
            "keyword": {
                "color": "#4B849B"
            }
        },
        {
            "filter": "06",
            "keyword": {
                "color": "#4B849B"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I just found this: `Starting March 27, 2019, all app submissions for iPhone or iPad, including universal apps, will require screenshots for iPhone XS Max or the 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd generation).`I guess, I have to use XS Max in addition to  what I had so far with the 8 Plus....

Comment: hmm, nope! Adding `iPhone Xs Max` to the `Snapfile`devices is not helping since `frameit` produces Xs-Max screenshots of size [1413 × 2844] but the App Store only allows [1242 × 2688]. Therefore again still same issue. Can anybody offer a solution to this ?

Comment: Which one is the question you want answered here?

Comment: You write "But having updated to newest iOS-, Swift- and Xcode-versions now suddenly breaks my working example of Fastlane.", but then all the rest sounds like this never really worked before. Was this broken by your update or did this never run successfully yet?

Comment: `frameit` should produce a image of a different size if you _only_ add a device frame (it adds a frame around the screenshot that keeps its size), but create an image of the originals size if you _also_ place the framed screenshot on a background with e.g. padding and text. From your description it is not clear what is happening.

Comment: Thank you janpio. To answer your first question: before updating versions, everything worked. I changed from `capture_screenshots(..)` to `snapshot (with Snapfile)`. I don't see why this could be the issue. Therefore, yes, it did work before the update and it seems no longer after the update. About your padding and text hint: I have `padding` and `background` defined in the Framefile.json file (see above). The only thing that changed inside this Framefile (compared to before the update) is: I added `stack_title`, `title_below_image` and `show_complete_frame`. Could these be the problem ?

Comment: (1) `snapshot`, `capture_ios_screenshots` and `capture_screenshots` are aliased for the identical code. (2) If it worked before, you can compare the size of the framed screenshots - did something change there? (3) And yes, changing the configuration could of course change things - go back to your old configuration to see if it works with the current versions then.

Comment: Thank you janpio. Oh no - silly me! I found the mistake: My `.gitignore` file contained `fastlane/screenshots` which prevented all my `Framefile.json` changes from taking effect ! And since I am working with GitLab CI, all my `git push` did not deliver any of my fastlane configuration-changes (but still triggered a new pipeline - all with old configs unfortunately). Your sorting out the issue helped, made me look deeper and I thank you for that !

Comment: Great, divide and conquer worked once again :)

Answer (score 4):

For those who bump into `frameit` spitting "Unsupported screen size" error, here is a scriptable way to resolve the issue.

1. Go to [this file](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/frameit/lib/frameit/device_types.rb#L79) to check the accepted screen size for all devices.
2. Use [`magick`](https://imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to reframe the raw screenshot to the dimension required for the desired device. An example command to resize the screenshot to fit iPhone 12 Pro Max is like this

```sh
magick $file -resize "1284x2778"\! $file
```

3. After resizing, run `frameit`.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/frameit/lib/frameit/editor.rb) of Frameit will find that it only resizes the final image when `is_complex_framing_mode`.

For `is_complex_framing_mode` to be true, it needs background and title( or keyword).

Besides, the default value of `show_complete_frame` is false. I set it to true, too.

I find this way will generate correct size of framed images to submit to App Store Connect.

Here is the Framefile.json

```
{
    "default": {
        "title": {
            "color": "#0000ff01",
            "text": "."
            },
        "show_complete_frame":true,
        "background": "./background.jpg",
        "padding": 1
        },
    "data": []
}
```